# realpath dirname confusion

Tags: php, windows

I have this code in a config file I am building:

```
define("PROCESSOR_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/usermanager/processors'));
define("LIBRARY_PATH", PROCESSOR_PATH.'/library');
define("TEMPLATE_PATH", realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/usermanager/assets/templates'));
```

if I call any of these constants after including my config file I just get nothing. so even if I do just this:

```
echo PROCESSOR_PATH;
```

Nothing is echoed. Can someone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure the path exists, it seems `realpath` is returning `FALSE`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

realpath() returns false if the directory does not exist. So that would be a fair reason.

If that's not the reason, then you should isolate your problem:

1. copy your project
2. remove all the code that is not related to the issue
3. if you can't find the solution with the isolated problem, post the code

Comment: the path exists but in trying to isolate the problem, I just found that removing realpath() just sorted me out. but I see this used everywhere, in php frameworks. so why does this not work on windows? cos my files exist. I will post my code and see what you think. Cheers